# Date Picker display a value of 01/01/0000

Tags: c#, wpf, datepicker

I am not sure how this became the display value as I have not specified this anywhere in my application.

```
<DatePicker Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="3" 
    Height="25" 
    HorizontalAlignment="Left"
    Margin="12,1,0,0" 
    x:Name="datePicker_dob" 
    Validation.Error="Validation_Error" 
    SelectedDate="{Binding UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged,
                   Path= dob,
                   ValidatesOnDataErrors=True,
                   NotifyOnValidationError=True}" 
    VerticalAlignment="Top" 
    Width="115" 
    SelectedDateFormat="Short" />
```

Comment: Have you tried anything so far? Please read [faq] and [ask]

Comment: That's the "default" value of `DateTime`. So if you had an uninitialized instance variable, for example, you'd get that.

Comment: Can you give us a little more info? Is it bound to anything? What does the XAML look like?

Comment: <DatePicker Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="3" Height="25" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="12,1,0,0" x:Name="datePicker_dob" 
                    Validation.Error="Validation_Error" SelectedDate="{Binding UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged,Path= dob,ValidatesOnDataErrors=True,NotifyOnValidationError=True}"  VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="115" SelectedDateFormat="Short" />

Comment: I tried to set a date by doing this in the constructor of the window by this.datePicker_dob.SelectedDate = DateTime.Today

Comment: @Dilanka, can you paste the code snippet where you attempted the set?

Comment: So it's bound to 'dob' then. You should check how that's being initialised. As others have said, it looks like it's uninitialised.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer is in your question :) As you have not specified the value, its showing the minValue. You just need to set it some value like today's date

Comment: I tried the following, but no luck; 
       public NewHire() {
            Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = new CultureInfo("en-US");
          
           InitializeComponent();
           grid_EmployeeData.DataContext = _employee;
          // this.datePicker_startDate.DisplayDate= new DateTime(2005,01,01); 
           this.datePicker_dob.SelectedDate = DateTime.Today;  
           
        }

Comment: setting it works for me. i had to remoe your bindings though. maybe there is an issue in your binding

Comment: I guess, it is coming from my binding.

Comment: when i do a binding like ......... SelectedDate="{Binding UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged,Path= dob,ValidatesOnDataErrors=True,NotifyOnValidationError=True}......................................... is there a way to specify the default value within as well?

Comment: I needed to pass the value through my binding object. sorry to confuse you.

Answer (score 5):

That's the value of an empty DateTime.  (`new DateTime()` or `DateTime.MinValue`)

Comment: how would i change this? I tried doing it on the constructor like i normally do.

Answer (score 0):

In your class you can add a property called `dob` like so:

```
private DateTime _dob;
public DateTime dob 
{
    get { return _dob; }
    set {_dob = value; }
}
```

Then initialise it from your constructor:
    dob = new DateTime...